# break javascript chain if GET request returns a 404 error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http-status-code-404

I am wondering how to break a chain of functions in angular if an API call returns a 404 error, and to continue with the chain if it is a 200 response. I want to execute a string of functions, one of which is a GET request to an API. This either returns a 200 success or 404 error. If it is a 200 I wish for the chain to continue executing, while if it is a 404 error, I want this to break.

Is this possible? Am I approaching this correctly?

My code is below:

In my service.js file

```
function breakIfErrorReturned () = {
     promiseChain = saveSignupData(Data)
          .then(doPreTest)
          .then(TestResource.doTestPayment)
          .then(makeFinalRailsCall(id))
          .then(sendAnalytics)

      return promiseChain;
}

function makeFinalRailsCall(tracking_id){
     return service.finalTestCheck.checkPackage({tracking_id:tracking_id})
        .$promise.then(function (data) {
            console.log(data)
         }, function (errorResponse) {
            return;
         }); 
 }
```

Comment: You probably want to use `.catch()` method, assuming Angular uses normal JS promises. [Bluebird docs on how `catch()` works.](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md#catchfunction-handler---promise)

Comment: If it's a 404 error, won't that automagically break the chain, and go to the next error handler or catch handler?

Comment: I thought so too, but it doesnt, it carries on, with an API post error in the middle of the console.  @KevinB

Comment: You'll always get the error in the console if it's an http error, that can't be avoided.

Comment: @KevinB I know that, I mean that the error is shown and the expected outcome from the rest of the chain is shown. Meaning the 404 has not broken the chain

Comment: returning a value in the second .then callback causes it to continue as if nothing is wrong. don't do that. you returned undefined.

Comment: for example, if you run the following code in your console that creates a promise and rejects it, it ends up resolving instead of rejecting because i returned a string in the error handler rather than throwing a new error or omitting the callback all together. `new Promise(function (resolve, reject){reject('foo');})
    .then(function () {},function () {return 'bar';}).then(function (d){console.log('success',d);}, function(d){console.log('fail', d);});`

Comment: The catch statement worked @Dropped.on.Caprica

Comment: @PaulFitzgerald Sweet, glad it helped.  You can use the `.catch()` at the end of the chain to do a sort of "catch all" for any errors that happen, or put them between function calls if you need to handle each error case differently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By adding a `catch()` statement to my code allowed me to break the chain if a 404 error was received from the GET request.

```
function makeFinalRailsCall(tracking_id){
     return service.finalTestCheck.checkPackage({tracking_id:tracking_id})
        .$promise.then(function (data) {
            console.log(data)
        }).catch(function(err){
                console.log(err)
            }); 
        }
```